# Laravel Filter, Set Variable

Tags: php, timezone, laravel

I am not sure if I am doing this correct but I wanted to basically use a filter to check if the user has set their timezone before every web request, therefore if they have not I want to load a popup box requesting them to do so. However, I have only found out how to redirect in the filter, is there a way I can set a variable which the route can then use?

Comment: where are you checking for the time zone? where do you want to redirect? what have you tried? can you past your code

Comment: There are many fact missing in your question: where are you saving information about time zone set? What does that filter redirection mean? Anyway, I recomend you saving time zone in cookies and check it via javascript. But keep in mind javascript can be bypassed by the user.

Answer (score 1):

without more info - this is a generic solution:

```
$time_zone = // where ever you checking if the time_zone is set?

if (is_null($time_zone))
{
   redirect ('/somewhere/set_timezone');
}
else
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to add a variable to your view, you can do it like this in your filter:

```
View::share('timezone_set', false);
```

Another way is to use view composers.